# how to generate a csr key BY OPEN SSL?

Tags: x509certificate, csr, ovh

I need for a certif  to make an electronic sign , so for that I have to generate a csr key from my OVH server , I follow the instruction over here

https://www.tbs-internet.com/php/HTML/pages/aideCreatCSR.php: so i tried this commande : 
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -out http://www.mycarrosse.com/.rsa.csr -keyout http://www.mycarrosse.com/.rsa.pkey -subj "/C=FR/ST=Ile-de-France/L=Paris/O=MyCarrosse/CN=http://www.mycarrosse.com/"

after excute it , i ve alwyes this problem

Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key

.........+++

.................+++

writing new private key to 'http://www.mycarrosse.com/.rsa.pkey'

http://www.mycarrosse.com/.rsa.pkey: No such file or directory

1588:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.40.1/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:356:fopen('http://www.mycarrosse.com/.rsa.pkey','w')

1588:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.40.1/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:358:

error in req

NB : the file rsa.pkey is on the  server

Any idea please

Answer (score 1):

The file file has to be on the local file system: [fopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) 
Try this instead:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 -out www.mycarrosse.com.sha256.csr -keyout www.mycarrosse.com.rsa.key -subj "/C=FR/ST=Ile-de-France/L=Paris/O=MyCarrosse/CN=www.mycarrosse.com"
```

Check the CSR content:

```
openssl req -in www.mycarrosse.com.sha256.csr -noout -text
```

And upload the files afterwards if you want.